# Rainwater off the roof ok for plants?

Tags: houseplants, watering

Is it ok to use the rainwater off the roof, water comes off the roof into the gutters, can we use this rainwater for plants?

Answer (score 5):

Yes - many people fit a water butt or rain barrel to the down pipe from the guttering round the roof, and use the water as and when they need to. It does depend where you live though, in some areas, rain water collection is banned https://www.leaffilter.com/blog/home-exteriors/roofing-gutters/6-reasons-save-rainwater/

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it depends on whether your roof has lead lining that rain water will flow over before getting to the gutter that you're using to collect the water.